# Creating an Updater

Tags: java, io

I'm currently trying to implement a updater for an app I'm writing.
The process currently looks as follows:

- Extract the updater.jar from the classpath (e.g. the app.jar) to the system's temp directory
- open a socket to listen for termination requests by the updater
- start the updater.jar
- the updater then checks whether an updater is available
- if an update is available, the updater sends a termination request to the app (via the opened socket)
- the updater downloads the new release to the systems temp directory
- **the updater copy's all files from the new release to the app's base dir (overwriting existing files)**

The problematic part in this process is the file copy of the new release into the app's basedir as some files in the app's base dir may be locked for some reason (i.e. the user opened a file in this dir).
So it could happen that some files have been copied and some haven't - leaving an inconsistent state and possibly not executable app.
What I did to prevent this situation is to check if there's any locked file in the app's basedir prior to copying the new files. I've written a util method for this purpose:

```
public static boolean isLocked(File pFile){
        if (pFile == null || !pFile.exists()){
            return false;
        }

        if (!pFile.canWrite()) return true;
        if (!pFile.renameTo(pFile)) return true;

        try {
            final FileChannel tFileChannel = FileChannel.open(pFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            final FileLock tLock = tFileChannel.tryLock();
            try {
                if (tLock == null){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    tLock.release();
                }
            } finally {
                tFileChannel.close();
            }
        } catch (final IOException | OverlappingFileLockException ex) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But I still think that this process is pretty error-prone as I don't know if the `isLocked()` method supplies reliable results under all circumstances.
And even if so, the locked state is only valid at the time the method is called -> the file may be locked immadiately after the call (by an anti-virus scanner for example).
So my question is: Is there is a more reliable way to copy a set of files? Maybe in some kind of rollback-able file transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i am overlooking something - but isn't the single correct answer to ensure that YOUR updater locked all files before starting its work?

It tries to lock on all files; and only when it "owns" all the relevant files, it starts its work?!